# Why the screenshot is blurred even though the `.captureResolution` is set to `.best` - ScreenCaptureKit - macOS

Tags: xcode, screencapturekit

Why the screenshot is blurred even though the `.captureResolution` is set to `.best` and `configuration.width` is set to `3840 * 2`.

It outputs the image in the size set with the `configuration.width`, but still blurred regardless of the high resolution image it produces.

I'm trying to capture as image (screenshot), not as video.

I don't expect the quality more than my current display, however, the output is worse than the current display.
When I take a screenshot with macOS standard screenshot tool, then the quality is perfect. Seems only the screenshot manager is not working properly.

**Errors:** `No errors`

```
@objc func takeScreenshot() {
    Task {
        do {
            let content = try await SCShareableContent.excludingDesktopWindows(false, onScreenWindowsOnly: false)
            guard let mainDisplayID = NSScreen.main?.deviceDescription[NSDeviceDescriptionKey("NSScreenNumber")] as? CGDirectDisplayID,
                  let display = content.displays.first(where: { $0.displayID == mainDisplayID }) else { return }
            
            let configuration = SCStreamConfiguration()
            configuration.captureResolution = .best
            configuration.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 400, y: 400, width: 800, height: 800)
            configuration.width = 3840 * 2
            configuration.height = 2160 * 2
            configuration.pixelFormat = kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA
            configuration.preservesAspectRatio = true
            configuration.capturesAudio = false
            configuration.scalesToFit = false

            let filter = SCContentFilter(display: display, excludingWindows: [])
            
            let capturedImage = try await SCScreenshotManager.captureImage(contentFilter: filter, configuration: configuration)

            let nsImage = NSImage(cgImage: capturedImage, size: NSZeroSize)
            self.imageView.image = nsImage

        } catch {
            print("Error capturing screen: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.
I found that it will become blurred if `sourceRect` is set.
So I replace `sourceRect` with image cropping.